# Set theory proof, $\exists g(g\colon A\twoheadrightarrow C)$ or $\exists h(h\colon C\hookrightarrow B)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be such that $|A \cup B|=|C \times C|$. Prove that $\exists g(g\colon A\twoheadrightarrow C)\lor \exists h(h\colon C\hookrightarrow B)$ ($h$ is injection and $g$ surjection).

Comment: [See here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting in MathJax.

Comment: And [see here](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=mse+how+to+ask+a+good+question&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) for how to ask a question. What have You tried?

Comment: I added $ but nothing happened. Cup is union times is just CxC

Comment: I've fixed your $\rm\LaTeX$. If you want to get some actual responses, rather than closing votes, I suggest that you add some more information to the question. For example, where do you find the difficulty? Did you try *anything*? Engage with the question, and tell us how it worked. As a first step, assume that there is no such $g$ and try to use the bijection from $A\cup B\to C\times C$ to prove that there is some $h$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f:\color{red}A\cup \color{blue}B\to C\times C$ be a bijection, and view $C\times C$ as a large square of pairs $(c,c')$. I will call $c$ the row of $(c,c')$ and $c'$ the column of $(c,c')$. I'll also say that $(c,c')$ is $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ if $(c,c')=f(a)$ for some $a\in \color{red}A$, and otherwise we see $(c,c')=f(b)$ for some $b\in\color{blue}B$, and I will call $(c,c')$ $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$.

Suppose every row contains a red pair $\color{red}{(c,c')}$. Let $\pi:C\times C\to C$ be the map that sends a pair $(c,c')$ to its row $\pi(c,c')=c$, then the composition $\pi\circ f:A\to C$ is a surjection.

Otherwise, let $c\in C$ be a row such that it contains only blue pairs $\color{blue}{(c,c')}$. Let $\sigma:C\to C\times C$ be the map that sends $c'$ to the blue pair $\color{blue}{(c,c')}$, then $f^{-1}\circ \sigma:C\to B$ is an injection.

Comment: What a beautiful answer!

Comment: Can you always look at the cartesian product of C as a square(having defined rows and columns)? Even when C is uncountable?

Comment: @yolo Sure, it'd be an uncountable square, but a square nevertheless. In a certain sense, the definition of a square is something multiplied by itself, cardinality has not much to do with it.